# Showing dataframe CRS in Status Bar in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

Is it possible to show the name of the current coordinate reference system being used in the active dataframe in the status bar of ArcMap 10?

I have searched for scripts but have not found anything appropriate.

Comment: You can add it to layout: Insert -> Dynamic text -> Coordinates system

Comment: Per @Geog comment, you only need this tag for the name, Coordinate System: <dyn type="dataFrame" name="Layers" property="sr" srProperty="name"/>

Comment: Thanks.....still not sure that is what I want. I wanted to program it into the ArcMap interface in the status bar...not to display in the dataframe as text.